# How to cut string coming from serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I receive data from a serial comport and I use `ReadLine` to get this data. Here is the data:

```
#MASTERPOSA,COM1,0,21.5,FINESTEERING,1544,340322.000,02000008,5009,4655;
SOL_COMPUTED,NARROW_INT,51.11604599076,-114.03855412002,1055.7756,16.9000,
WGS84,0.0090,0.0086,0.0143,"AAAA",0.0,0.0,13,13,13,12,0,0,0,0*a72e8d3f
```

I want to get the data until `AAAA`, which is

```
#MASTERPOSA,COM1,0,21.5,FINESTEERING,1544,340322.000,02000008,5009,4655;
SOL_COMPUTED,NARROW_INT,51.11604599076,-114.03855412002,1055.7756,16.9000,
WGS84,0.0090,0.0086,0.0143
```

I used the `TrimEnd` method but it does not work:

```
textBox2.Text = data.TrimEnd(' ', '"').ToString();
```

Comment: You have a complicate text file you are parsing. Looking at a piece of the file doesn't help a lot from my 45 years of parsing text files.  You have two different types of lines (ending in returns) 1) Lines starting with a # 2) Data lines that are separated by commas.  So get the lines that are CSV and split by the comma which ill solve issue.

Comment: You have to escape a double quotes

Comment: Data is originally comes from serial port with quotes, since I do not remove them, I try to get data until "AAAA".

Comment: Is and will it always be exactly `"AAAA"`?

Comment: You can also use regular expression: `.+?(?=."AAAA")`. Matched anything until `."AAAA"`

Comment: @MindSwipe, It comes always with quotes but the characters changes

Comment: Ok, then the easy solution of finding the index of `"AAAA"` and cutting everything after it wont work. Do you know if there will ever be a quote before `"AAAA"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cut" the string with `Substring()` method from the first index to the index of *",AAAA"*

```
private static void Example()
{
  string target = "#MASTERPOSA,COM1,0,21.5,FINESTEERING,1544,340322.000,02000008,5009,4655; SOL_COMPUTED,NARROW_INT,51.11604599076,-114.03855412002,1055.7756,16.9000, WGS84,0.0090,0.0086,0.0143,\"AAAA\",0.0,0.0,13,13,13,12,0,0,0,0*a72e8d3f";
  string newstring = target.Substring(0, target.IndexOf(",\"AAAA\""));
  Console.WriteLine(newstring);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the `"AAAA"` index first (with escaped double quotes), then use [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method

```cs
var index = str.IndexOf("\"AAAA\"", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var result = str.Substring(0, index - 1);
```

It gives you the following result

> #MASTERPOSA,COM1,0,21.5,FINESTEERING,1544,340322.000,02000008,5009,4655;
> SOL_COMPUTED,NARROW_INT,51.11604599076,-114.03855412002,1055.7756,16.9000,
> WGS84,0.0090,0.0086,0.0143

Comment: This won't exactly work, as OP stated in a comment that the characters in between the quotes change but the quotes stay

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "#MASTERPOSA,COM1,0,21.5,FINESTEERING,1544,340322.000,02000008,5009,4655; SOL_COMPUTED,NARROW_INT,51.11604599076,-114.03855412002,1055.7756,16.9000, WGS84,0.0090,0.0086,0.0143,\"AAAA\",0.0,0.0,13,13,13,12,0,0,0,0*a72e8d3f";
    
Regex regex = new Regex($"(^.*?)(\"AAAA\")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);//or other options

string newstring =  regex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
```

You can use any regex. In this example:

- Groups[0]: required text with `"AAAA"`
- Groups[1]: required text without `"AAAA"`
- Groups[2]: `"AAAA"`